# iOS 11: Pop view controller with scrollView inside navigation controller with opaque navbar result in weird content animation during transition

Tags: ios, ios11

Pop view controller with scrollView inside navigation controller with opaque navbar result in weird content animation during transition

The content will be somewhere below its original position during transition, and interactive pop will make this very obvious.

Enabling Safe area does not fix this.

Answer (score 8):

It is a bug in iOS 11 I believe. 
Here's a rdar about it:
http://openradar.appspot.com/34465226

You can walk around this issue by check the `Extend Edges: Under Opaque Bars` box in storyboard or set `[self setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:YES]` manually in code.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks. Unfortunately I've found that if I also include `[self setEdgeForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone];` the animation bug comes back.

Comment: Just so you know: this should be fixed in 11.2, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046282/6863743