# UIViewController: extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars and scroll view offset

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

My app's view hierarchy is pretty straightforward: a `UINavigationController` contains a `UITableViewController`. The navigation controller's navigation bar is opaque, which causes some strange inset behavior of the table view during navigation transitions, seen here:

[image: Navigation Inset Issue]

To remedy this, I'm setting `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `true` on the `UITableViewController`. Doing so properly extends the view beneath the navigation bar, but changes the behavior of the table view's `contentOffset` in a way that I don't quite understand. With this property set to `true`, the Y-value of the table view's `contentOffset` reports that it is offset higher than it should be by the current height of the navigation bar (i.e. scrolling the table view 1pt, it reports that its y-offset is -63pts).

This made me think that the navigation controller was automatically managing the scroll view's `contentInset`, like it does for translucent bars. But I couldn't see any evidence that the scroll view had content insets set in `scrollViewDidScroll()`. Even with `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` set to `false` on the table view controller, the content offset wasn't right, so it seems it's nothing to do with the insets.

[Apple's documentation about `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621404-extendedlayoutincludesopaquebars) doesn't mention any effect on the behavior of a scroll view's content offset. Changing the `contentInset` of the table view unfortunately doesn't solve this.

I tried changing the table view controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout` property to force it to extend without affecting the scroll view, but it seems this property is powerless against opaque bars.

Is there some hidden behavior with `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` that borks up a scroll view's content offset? Or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

Comment: Feels too easy — this worked! I had tried it earlier, but only in conjunction with extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars set to true. Leaving the opaque bars property at its default false and including this works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by [@beebcon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919752/6863743) before, this was indeed a bug (Apple engineer confirmed on twitter) and should be fixed in iOS 11.2.

[image: first tweet]
[image]

*(I'm sorry I used images, but this way it doesn't go away in case the tweets disappear)*

Answer (score 3):

**Background on what's going on**---

`extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` essentially tells your view to behave as if the navigation bars are translucent. Your view's frame then will begin at the top of (underneath) the navigation bar, rather than at the bottom of the bar.

The navigation controller then sees that you have a scroll view, and automatically insets it to compensate for the area covered by the bar.

In iOS *10*, you could query `contentInset` and see the `top = 64` inset. However, in iOS 11, `contentInset` is strictly for any custom insets you control -- you should use `adjustedContentInset`, which is the sum total of your custom insets and any safe area insets.

```
adjustedContentInset - 
The insets derived from the content insets and the safe area of the scroll view.

contentInset - 
The custom distance that the content view is inset from the safe area or scroll view edges.
```

So really, the y offset of -63 makes sense, it's the same thing you'd see if your bars were translucent.

---

**The issue you're talking about**, which your GIF demonstrates, is I think a bug (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397291/2145198).

While JoniVR's answer should work, **I solved it in my projects** by setting `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`.

Though it's probably not a big deal either way you solve it, extending the layout feels like better practice to me, rather than changing the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`. Setting that to `never` has a wider range of potential effects; you're telling it to never care about safe area, no matter where the safe area is coming from. Safe area could change (like on rotation) or if your controller is presented in different contexts / containers (like tab bar or not).

Comment: `contentInset` vs. `adjustedContentInset` makes total sense — I had completely missed that there was a new property for this.

Comment: Yeah it's annoying -- I added a category method on `UIScrollView` I call `totalContentInset` which checks `if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))` to give me the adjusted, or else the regular insets